# ABP Framework API Scope

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I cloned MicroserviceDemo solution, before run project PublicWebsite.Host, I commented below code in PublicWebSiteHostModule.cs, but why PublicWebsite.Host still can access PublicWebSiteGateway, ProductService and BloggingService? In my view, I think app only access to required scopes. (Other hand, comment or don't comment below code, PublicWebsite.Host still run correctly. Sorry for my English).

Thanks you!

```
            context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                    options.ClientId = configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthServer:ClientSecret"];
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("role");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("phone");

                    //options.Scope.Add("PublicWebSiteGateway");
                    //options.Scope.Add("ProductService");
                    //options.Scope.Add("BloggingService");

                    options.ClaimActions.MapAbpClaimTypes();
                });
```

Comment: is your project `abp` or `aspnetboilerplate`? (they are quite different)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my project is ABP and I understood my problems, in MicroserviceDemo app, some API is not authorize, and then it's called without error. Best regard!